# Push Notifications warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, ios-4.2, apple-push-notifications

I am working with push notifications in my app. but I am getting this warning:
Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSData *'

the code where its getting warning is:

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Here you send the deviceToken to your server.. 
deviceToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

NSLog(@"Device Token: %@",deviceToken);
}
```

Can anybody tell me why did I got that warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a separate NSString called deviceTokenStr as deviceToken itself is an NSData object and it is causing the error

```
    NSString *deviceTokenStr = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:      @"<" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"Device Token: %@",deviceTokenStr);
```